# Docker container port conflict Portainer/Sonarqube

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, sonarqube, docker-machine, portainer

I'm using portainer, and I'm using jenkins for continuous integration. It's all working fine.
But now I'm trying to use Sonarqube with jenkins, but portainer and sonarqube have a default port 9000, and only the first container running works, to work one I have to stop the other container.

I've tried to build the container with a different port, but it always put automatically the 9000 port as well.

Anyone know how can I change this default port? How can I solve this port conflict?
I'd like to use sonarqube in a different port.

> docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 7000:7000 sonarqube

I'm using CentOS, and when I run this command the container stay with port 7000/tcp and 9000/tcp.
And the same happens if I try to change portainer's container port to other number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide your docker-compose.yml or docker command. Basically you can map to another port using -p <host_port>:<container_port> as argument in [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) or inside the service definition of docker-compose.yml.

```
docker run -p 9999:9000 // you can access from host on port 9999
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new with docker, but I've never used this docker-compose, I think I don't use it. But the command I used is: 'docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 7000:7000 sonarqube' I tried to change the port to 7000, so I could use to access from inside or outside the VM.

Comment: try: docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 7000:9000 sonarqube